# SpriteKit node selection and touch management

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch, sprite-kit

I am writing a small sprite-kit game. In it there will be several nodes on the screen. When the user taps one of them it will become selected. I did this by implementing touched did begin on the `SKSpriteNode` subclass that I use (it adds another overlay node to the tapped node to indicate that it is selected).

The user should be able to select another node by tapping on it. **How do I notify the already selected node that the user selected another node? Notifications?** I don't think that I could use the `touches did begin` method on the scene, because I also want this:

- if the user has selected a node and taps outside on the scene then the selected node should rotate to point to the tapped area.
- However if the user has no selected node that he could scroll the scene (it's larger than the screen size).
- The user should deselect any selected node by tapping on the scene (where there are no nodes).

This is a lot of touch handling... What's the bast way to do this?
Thank you in advance..

Comment: store that subclass instance as a classproperty

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **`NSNotificationCenter`**. This would give you the most flexible solution.

When a node gets tapped it would post a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"YourNodeTappedNotification" 
                                                    object:self];
```

Other nodes, scene, etc, could then handle this event if they previously registered for the notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:yourObject 
                                         selector:@selector(nodeTapped:)        
                                             name:@"YourNodeTappedNotification" 
                                           object:nil];
```

You can additionaly have more types of notifications. For example for deselecting a node, etc.

Comment: That's what I have been thinking about ... but ... doesn't apple recommend not to use notifications for any type of UI activity as notifications may severely lower app performance???

Comment: It really depends on the use case and the way you handle the notifications. In your case, you will not post many notifications so I don't see any potential performance problems here.